# Reading JSON response and getting type error for field in response even though field exists javaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

my previously working code has stopped reading one of the inner fields in my JSON response, saying there is a type error even though the field exists.

Here's the response I'm reading:

```
organic_results: [{title: "Montessori Wooden Educational Object Permanence Box With Tray For Toddlers Kid",…},…]
0: {title: "Montessori Wooden Educational Object Permanence Box With Tray For Toddlers Kid",…}
condition: "Brand new"
extensions: ["Buy It Now", "Almost gone", "85 sold"]
price: {raw: "AU $23.85", extracted: 23.85}
extracted: 23.85
raw: "AU $23.85"
shipping: "Postage not specified"
subtitle: "Unbranded"
thumbnail: "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/1eMAAOSw5Jdf9SA9/s-l225.jpg"
title: "Montessori Wooden Educational Object Permanence Box With Tray For Toddlers Kid"
```

If I hover over the fields I see the path organic_results[0].price.extracted

In my code I'm looping through the results and adding them all, then dividing to get the average sale price.

```
const { organic_results } = await response.json();

    //find total price by adding all prices from the found records
    const averagePrice = () => {
    let total = 0;
    let average = 0;

    for (let index = 0; index < organic_results.length; index++) {
      let priceMinusPostage = organic_results[index].price.extracted - 9; //Guestimate of average postage
      total = total+priceMinusPostage;
    }

    average = (total/organic_results.length).toFixed(2);
    return average;
    }
```

When I run my code I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extracted')
```

What's the dumb thing that I'm just not seeing atm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in this way, it should work if you have it in response

```
organic_results[index]?.price?.extracted
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks Evren